# Atmel Software Framework. Confusion with USART example

Tags: atmel, usart

I'm trying to get the following basic USART example working on a SAM4S:

http://asf.atmel.com/docs/3.4.1/sam4s/html/sam_usart_quickstart.html#usart_basic_use_case

I am using a custom PCB board with a SAM4S16B MCU on it.

After setting up my project in Atmel Studio as instructed and attempting to compile, I am getting a number of errors of the form:

Error   4   'PINS_USART_MASK' undeclared (first use in this function)   C:\Users\Nick\Dropbox\Uni Work 13\comms\comms\src\main.c    94  5   comms

My question is wondering whether the following lines are placeholders that expect something else to be substituted in the define values?

#define USART_SERIAL_PIO             PINS_USART_PIO

#define USART_SERIAL_TYPE            PINS_USART_TYPE

#define USART_SERIAL_PINS            PINS_USART_PINS

#define USART_SERIAL_MASK            PINS_USART_MASK